# Post Data to the action result when Dropdown list change in ASP.NET MVC using jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have Created JqGrid for loading some records like below.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#jqgRequests').jqGrid({
                defaults: {
                    recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
                    emptyrecords: "No Request Found",
                    loadtext: "Loading...",
                    pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}"
                },
                //url from wich data should be requested
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadRequest")',
                //type of data
                datatype: 'json',
                //url access method type
                mtype: 'POST',
                //columns names
                colNames: ['Is Approved','Requestor', 'Request Type', 'Request Date', 'Approved Date', 'Package','Comments','RequestID', '','',''],
                //columns model
                colModel: [

                         { name: 'IsApproved',
                               formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                   var status = rowObject[0];
                                   if (status == 1) {
                                       return '<input type="checkbox" name="approval" checked disabled="disabled">';
                                   }

                                   else if(status==2) {

                                    return '<img  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/reject.jpg")"></img>';

                                   }
                                   else{
                                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="approval" disabled="disabled" >';
                                   }

                               },sortable:false, align: 'center', width: 80, index: 'subColumn'
                           },
                         { name: 'Requestor', index: 'Requestor', width: 170, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'Request Type', index: 'RequestType', width: 90, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'RequestDate', index: 'RequestDate', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'FullDateTime', newformat: 'd/m/Y g:i:s A' }, width: 120, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'ApprovedDate', index: 'ApprovedDate', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'FullDateTime', newformat: 'd/m/Y g:i:s A' }, width: 120, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'Package', index: 'Package', width: 150, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'Comments', index: 'Comments', width: 300, align: 'left' },
                         { name: 'RequestID', index: 'RequestID', width: 1, align: 'left',hidden:true },

                         { name: 'Approve',
                             formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                 var status = rowObject[0];
                                 if(status==1)
                                 {
                                 return  '@Html.ActionLink("Approve", null, null, new { @style = "color:blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return WarningPopup('Already approved');", href = "#" })';

                                 }
                                 else{
                                   var x = '@Html.ActionLink("Approve", null, null, new { @style = "color:Blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return ConfirmPopup('myId');", href = "#"  })';
//                                 var x = '@Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", "Dashboard", new { requestId = "myId" }, new { @style = "color:Blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to approve this request?');" })';
                                 return x.replace("myId",rowObject[7]);
                                 }
                             },sortable:false, align: 'left', width: 45
                         },
                           { name: 'Reject',
                             formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                                      var status = rowObject[0];
                                 if(status==2)
                                 {
                                 return  '@Html.ActionLink("Reject", null, null, new { @style = "color:blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return WarningPopup('Already rejected');", href = "#" })';

                                 }
                                 else{
                                  var x = '@Html.ActionLink("Reject", null, null, new { @style = "color:Blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return Rejectpopup('myId');", href = "#"  })';
                                // var x = '@Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", "Dashboard", new { requestId = "myId" }, new { @style = "color:Blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to reject this request?');" })';
                                 return x.replace("myId",rowObject[7]);
                                 }
                             },sortable:false, align: 'left', width: 60
                         },
                          { name: 'More',
                             formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
//                                var x = "<a class='btnMore' onclick='GetDetail('myId');' style = 'color:blue;font-weight:bold;' href='#'>More Detail</a>"
                             var x='@Html.ActionLink("Detail", null, null, new { @style = "color:blue;font-weight:bold;", onclick = "return GetDetail('myId');", href = "#" })';

                               return x.replace("myId",rowObject[7]);

                             },sortable:false, align: 'left', width: 80
                         }
                         ],
                //pager for grid
                pager: $('#jqgpRequests'),
                //number of rows per page
                rowNum: 25,
                //initial sorting column
                sortname: 'RequestID',
                //initial sorting direction
                sortorder: 'asc',
                //we want to display total records count
                viewrecords: true,
                //grid height
                height: '100%'
            });
        });
        </script>
```

### Action Result

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            public JsonResult LoadRequest(JqGridRequest request)
            {
                int totalRecords = _dashboardRepository.RequestCount;
                var response = new JqGridResponse()
                {
                    TotalPagesCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)request.RecordsCount),
                    PageIndex = request.PageIndex,
                    TotalRecordsCount = totalRecords
                };
                const string subColumn = "";
                foreach (var dashboard in _dashboardRepository.LoadAllRequests(request.SortingName, request.SortingOrder.ToString(), request.PageIndex, request.RecordsCount))
                {
                    response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord(dashboard.RequestID.ToString(), new List<object>()
                {
                    dashboard.IsApproved,
                    dashboard.Requestor,
                    dashboard.RequestType,
                    dashboard.RequestDate,
                    dashboard.ApprovedDate,
                    dashboard.Package,
                    dashboard.Comments,
                    dashboard.RequestID
                }));
                }
                return new JqGridJsonResult { Data = response };
            }
```

This jqGrid load when the page load. Also i have added a dropdown list for filtering. For this  i need to post some parameters for the JqGridRequest class . How can i possible this?

Comment: You wrote about dropdown as the main problem which you have, but the code which you posted contains *no* select element. Which dropdown list you mean? Do you use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) for filtering of data or you have some `<select>` outside of jqGrid?. In any way it's required more information of more HTML code which you use.

Comment: I have added custom dropdown list out side.not inside the jqgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dropdown id is `ddlFilter` you can write the JavaScript change event handler like this:

```
$('#ddlFilter').on('change', function(e) {
    $('#jqgRequests').setGridParam({ postData: { FilterValue: $(this).val(); } }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }]);
});
```

On server side you can create following view model for handling the post data:

```
public class PostDataViewModel
{
    public string FilterValue { get; set; }
}
```

And add it as one more parameter to your action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult LoadRequest(JqGridRequest request, PostDataViewModel postData)
{
    ...
}
```

Unless there is some specifc requirement or edge case you haven't describe in your question this should do the trick.

Comment: Your code is working fine.But i have one problem my jqGrid is reloading again and again

Comment: So second time reloading the post data become null

Comment: @JEMI Can you inspect the request with FireBug or Fiddler, because it seems like the second request is being triggered somewhere else (maybe there is some kind of POST or GET happening on the page). If you are causing request somehwere else in your page than you can skip the `.trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1 }])` part and either just set the `postData` in event handler, or define `postData` as function (in the way described by @Oleg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you can follow the suggestion from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935).

If you have for example `<select id="mySelect">...</select>` on the page you can use jqGrid option

```
postData: {
    myFilter: function () {
        return $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
    }
}
```

to send the value of the select box together with other standard jqGrid parameters (see `JqGridRequest`). If you want additionally to reload the grid after every changes of the select you can use `.trigger("reloadGrid")`. You need just set `change` and `keyup` event handler and calls `.trigger("reloadGrid")` it it require. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more code example.